# Python debugger not working in VSCode under venv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have the following settings.json

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\james\\OneDrive\\Programming Projects\\Python\\webscraper\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "\\Scripts\\pylint.exe"
}
```

and the following entry in launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I go to my file I want to debug and pick my `Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)` debugger, it greys out my breakpoints and shows this:

[image]

If, on the other hand, I set up a new interpreter, for example:

```
"C:\\Users\\james\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\python.exe"
```

It will run the debugger, but at the same time, it does not take my venv into account and so throws errors about missing modules (as it should).

[image]

Do you know where I might be going wrong?

Comment: your environment should be a SUBdir of the workspace, not the workspace is the environment

Comment: I'm not quite sure of the action. Do you mean I need to put all of my stuff inside a folder? Thank you for responding by the way!

Comment: the folder you opened in VSC IS the environment, wrong, it should be the parent folder of the environment

Comment: Should I also have the vscode folder in the parent folder?

Comment: yes, `workspaceFolder/.vscode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to mention here:

The environment should not have your files inside it, it's supposed to be something you use and throw away at a whim. Place project files outside of the environment you create. I laid mine out as a folder called "env" that I created using:

```
py -m venv env
```

and then after it was created, I activated it with

```
env/Scripts/activate
```

[image]

Second of all, don't forget to ensure your vscode folder is in that root folder, here are my settings for my configuration that ended up working.

[image]

This seemed to be really important:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--init-hook",
    "import sys; sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\james\\OneDrive\\Programming Projects\\Python')"
],
```

And just in case it wasn't clear how my folder structure now looks like. the `main.py`, `logic`, `models` and `services` folders are my own code. The `env` folder is the environment created with `venv`:

[image]

Just an extra bonus, don't forget to create a requirements.txt that stores libraries you use in your project

[image]

You can then install from that using:

```
py -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```